# Making API Requests to Grafana Local

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, grafana

I'm working on a group project to measure the efficiency of PGDBs and queries of PGDB data. We are going to have the user run an instance of Grafana locally and send requests to that URL to set up the users PG database. Once setup, we would then setup a dashboard with the information that we want access to and have it generate the graphs and statistics that we're looking for.

We're having trouble making the proper POST requests to Grafana. The requests seem to set up the user's datasource as a PGDB but the datasource isn't actually connected to the users DB.

```
{
"name": "Test_PG_DB",
"type": "postgres",
"url": "test_works",
"user": "test_works",
"access": "proxy",
"database": "test_works",
"Password": "test_not_working",
"basicAuth": false
}
```

Currently the password field is not properly setting up on Grafana, it just leaves it blank.

Am I making the request correctly?

Is there a way to setup a datasource with just a URI/URL?

Is there a better resource for making these GET/POST requests?

Is there another direction you would recommend going other than Grafana/local instance?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON you provided, password seems to be the only one capitalised « Password ».

Shouldn’t it be

```
{
"name": "Test_PG_DB",
"type": "postgres",
"url": "test_works",
"user": "test_works",
"access": "proxy",
"database": "test_works",
"password": "test_not_working",
"basicAuth": false
}
```

Also you could try the secureJsonData property:

```
{
"name": "Test_PG_DB",
"type": "postgres",
"url": "test_works",
"user": "test_works",
"access": "proxy",
"database": "test_works",
"secureJsonData": {
  "password": "abcdef"
},
"basicAuth": false
}
```

Comment: I tried it both ways, doesn't seem to work

Comment: Then try to add the field secureJsonData and put password within it.